# Ruby/node.js + Amazon SES: Is there an Amazon SES API?

Tags: node.js, ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ses

I have seen several gems that make use of Amazon SES. However, I can't find any API provided by Amazon to build a service without that gem.

How can I do what the gem does, without using the gem? That is really important for my app because I'm sending keys constantly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The API of Amazon SES is documented [here](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ses/).

Comment: That's not very helpful. I can+t seem to find an example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the gem [aws-ses](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses) is quite straightforward to use it.